# Can't find Payment Date in the Payment or Order class

Tags: payment

I'm working to an extension that needs to push to an external service every order and refund that happens on the shop. One of the needed infos it needs to pass is the **payment date** - and for the life of me I can't find it, neither in the payment class nor in the order class:
https://www.magentoextensions.org/documentation/class_magento_1_1_sales_1_1_model_1_1_order_1_1_payment.html
https://www.magentoextensions.org/documentation/interface_magento_1_1_sales_1_1_api_1_1_data_1_1_order_interface.html

Does someone know how to retrieve this information?
Shippings and Orders have the getCreatedAt() method, but I don't find it for Payments, nor do I find anything similar, though it occurs to me as a basic info that should be available.

Thanks everyone!

EDIT: here the column names of the table *sales_order_payment*

mysql> select * from sales_order_payment;
+-----------+-----------+------------------------+-------------------+-----------------+------------------+-----------------+------------------------+-------------------------+-----------------------------+----------------------+-----------------+-------------+-------------------+---------------------+------------------------+-------------------+----------------------+----------------+----------------------+------------------+-----------------+--------------+------------------+------------------+---------+-----------------------+------------------+------------------------+-------------+-----------+-----------------------+-------------+------------------------------+-------------------+---------------------+---------------+---------------+----------+---------+-----------+-------------+-----------+-----------------------+----------------+-------------------+------------------------+-------------+---------------------+---------------+---------------+-------------+----------------+-----------------------------------------+
| entity_id | parent_id | base_shipping_captured | shipping_captured | amount_refunded | base_amount_paid | amount_canceled | base_amount_authorized | base_amount_paid_online | base_amount_refunded_online | base_shipping_amount | shipping_amount | amount_paid | amount_authorized | base_amount_ordered | base_shipping_refunded | shipping_refunded | base_amount_refunded | amount_ordered | base_amount_canceled | quote_payment_id | additional_data | cc_exp_month | cc_ss_start_year | echeck_bank_name | method  | cc_debug_request_body | cc_secure_verify | protection_eligibility | cc_approval | cc_last_4 | cc_status_description | echeck_type | cc_debug_response_serialized | cc_ss_start_month | echeck_account_type | last_trans_id | cc_cid_status | cc_owner | cc_type | po_number | cc_exp_year | cc_status | echeck_routing_number | account_status | anet_trans_method | cc_debug_response_body | cc_ss_issue | echeck_account_name | cc_avs_status | cc_number_enc | cc_trans_id | address_status | additional_information

Answer (score 0):

One idea is to check if you can take the 'created_at' from the `sales_payment_transaction` table as reference.

Comment: Hi Diana, thanks for your answer - apparently there's no created_at field in that table.

Comment: hmmm, that's weird. can you please tell me which Magento version and edition are you using?

Comment: Magento CLI dev-2.4-develop. Cloned from GitHub less than a month ago.

Comment: Wait, I made a mistake: sales_payment_transaction is completely empty (Empty set). I pasted above sales_order_payment 's columns.